# PHP ternary operator doesn't parse inside class property?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why a ternary operator inside of a class will not parse. I think an example is the clearest way to show this.

This works fine:

```
$a = array(
    'a' => 'foo',
    'b' => 1 ? 'true' : 'false',
    'c' => 'baz',
);
print_r($a);

/* Array
   (
       [a] => foo
       [b] => true
       [c] => baz
    )
 */
```

But this doesn't even parse:

```
<?php

class Junk {
    private static $a = array(
        'a' => 'foo',
        'b' => 1 ? 'true' : 'false',
        'c' => 'baz',
    );

    public static function printA() {
        print_r(self::$a);
    }
}

Junk::printA();
```

I get the following message:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting ')' in junk.php on line 6
```

For the record, it doesn't work outside of an array declaration either:

```
private static $a = 1 ? 'true' : 'false';
```

gives the same error message.

Why doesn't this work? Is it just some weird bug in the parsing engine? I am completely baffled. The [manual on ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) states that the operator is an expression, which should always work on the right-hand side of an array assignment. I'm on PHP 5.4.28, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class property must be a constant expression.

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Fair enough; it's just an extremely unhelpful error message. Is there anywhere that defines exactly what a constant value is? I know it "must not depend on run-time information," but where is that defined? `static $a = 1;` works, but `static $a = (1)` doesn't. Likewise, my original code will always evaluate to 'true' (compilers in other languages would be able to figure that out, but I guess PHP doesn't).